# Updating Json values with a promise

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular-promise

I want to populate some values in Json that are being calculated with angular-promises and these value should be updated after certain events. 
I tried to call the factory which yields the values for example something like below and tried to call the functions GetWeeklyVal and GetDailyVal which are in charge of calculating the values :

```
this.salesList = 
    {"sales":[
        {   "id":"A1", "dailyValue": GetDailyVal('A1'), "weeklyValue": GetWeeklyVal('A1')},
        {   "id":"A2", "dailyValue": GetDailyVal('A2'), "weeklyValue": GetWeeklyVal('A2')}
    ]}
```

and in my controller I have:

```
$scope.sales= salesServices.salesList.sales;
```

but it didn't work. the values remain zero which is the default value in the application. 
Why the values are not being updated and what would be a better solution?

**update**

This is the portion of the code I call the calculation functions: (I skip the portion to get the values based on passed id in here)

```
function GetDailyVal(id){
    var dValue = 0;
    salesService.getSales();
    dValue = salesService.totalAmount;
    return dValue;
}
```

this is the factory

```
.factory('salesService', ['$http', '$q'],
function salesInvoiceService($http, $q) {

    var service = {
        sales: [],
        getSales: getSales,
        totalAmount: 0
    };
    return service;

    function getSales() {
        var def = $q.defer();
        var url = "http://fooAPI/salesinvoice/SalesInvoices"; //+ OrderDate filter

        $http.get(url)
          .success(function(data) {
            service.sales = data.d.results;
            setTotalAmount(service.sales);
            def.resolve(service.sales);
          })
          .error(function(error){
            def.reject("Failed to get sales");
          })
          .finally(function() {
            return def.promise;
         });
    }

    function setTotalAmount(sales){
        var sum = 0;
        sales.forEach(function (invoice){
            sum += invoice.AmountDC;
        });
        service.totalAmount = sum;
    }
})
```

Comment: first check GetDailyVal() & GetWeeklyVal() execute corretly or not.

Comment: I call those functions separately and they work and yield correct values but when I try to load the grid based on Json, it won't work anymore.

Comment: Can you show me some more code?

Comment: check this post, maybe it will give you a clue : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33706220/updating-array-object-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are some errors in your code.

I give some sample code here. I think this will help you.

This is a sample code in one of my application. Check it.

```
service.factory('Settings', ['$http','$q', function($http,$q) {
    return {
            AcademicYearDetails : function(Details) {
                return $http.post('/api/academic-year-setting', Details)
                .then(function(response) {
                    if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
                        return response.data;
                    } else {
                        return $q.reject(response.data);
                    }

                }, function(response) {
                    return $q.reject(response.data);
                });
            },
            newUser : function(details) {
        return $http.post('/api/new-user', details);
      }
```

}
}]);

Answer (score 0):

The reason why its not working is:

```
dailyValue: GetDailyVal('A1')
```

Here, GetDailyVal makes an async ajax call to an api. For handling async requests, you have to return a promise as follows in your GetDailyVal function as follows:

```
function GetDailyVal() {
    salesService.getSales().then(function(data) { //promise
        dValue = salesService.totalAmount;
        return dValue;
    })
}
```

Same thing need to be done for weeklyValue.

Comment: I can get the rest of values from my Json and load them in my grid. The issue is just with getting the values of the promises. should I put the portion of code for calculating the values as well?

Comment: do GetDailyVal and GetWeeklyVal get values from an api?

Comment: well I know why its not working because there is no promise for GetDailyVal and GetWeeklyVal in your controller. I am not sure how you can add the promise in the json object though...

Comment: best way imo would be to load the dailyValue and weeklyValue separately in a loop.

Comment: sorry for trouble but would you post a sample when you had time?

Comment: Edited the question. Try the solution now.