# Updating array object values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I want to update some values in global array that I keep in a factory.
I use the get method to get the data but set function somehow doesn't do its job and the value in the array doesn't get updated. What am I missing?

```
.factory('messageList', function () {
   var Messages = 
    [
        {   "title":"Cash in", "icon":"ion-social-euro", 
            "dailyValue": "0", "weeklyValue": "0", "monthlyValue": "0", 
            "category": "financial", "active": "true"
        },
        {   "title":"Sales orders", "icon":"ion-social-euro", 
            "dailyValue": "0", "weeklyValue": "0", "monthlyValue": "0", 
            "category": "sales", "active": "true"
        }
    ]

return {
   get: function() {
      return Messages;
   },
   set: function(title, key, newValue) {
       for (var i = 0; i < Messages.length; i++) {
          if(Messages[i].title == title){
            Messages[i].key = newValue;
          }
       }
   }
 }
})
```

This is how I attempt to update the values in the controller:

```
messageList.set("Sales orders","dailyValue", $Scope.sum);
```

Comment: Could you append the code where you're using this code? It doesn't look like it's complete code, but take out of context.

Comment: That's not JSON, that's a JavaScript array initializer (aka array literal) containing object initializers (object literals), or really in this case, we'd just say an array with objects in. JSON is a *textual* notation for data exchange. If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this is a sample data I get from http get call and store it in global array, update it client side and then post it again. I skipped that part because I didn't this it was relevant. but you are right the issue is not related directly to Json.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `key` is a variable, use this

```
Messages[i][key] = newValue;
```

`Messages[i].key` will look for an element in your object with key 'key' rather than a key with the value of your variable

Comment: Which is great (and correct), but **why** is an important part of answering a question.

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe it was so simple matter :)

Comment: I had to learn this at some stage not so long ago too - but you never forget afterwards!

Comment: indeed! not after this, I won't forget!